# Ubuntu Precise -- suspend wedges GDM -- help!

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, desktop, suspend

I've been a very happy Ubuntu user for many years, and worked my way past any number of problems, but I've never seen anything like this.

Recently I got a new machine and installed 12.04 Precise on it, and after some fiddling, it looked like everything was working fine. I just tried the suspend function for the first time, and on wakeup, GDM was seriously wedged -- a window popped up saying "System Error" and gave a bunch of details. I took screenshots -- I think it was a segfault thrown by simple-slave :

[image]

[image]

Now a reboot gets me to a low-res startup screen, saying "Ubuntu 12.04" and four dots that change from white to orange and back again, nothing more. I can use ctl-alt-F1 to get a command line, log in there, and run "startx" and I get the X display (including TwinView on my two monitors), the cursor works, but there's no desktop manager, no Dash, no way to go further that I can see. I've rebooted several times and this behavior isn't changing.

From the command line, I've tried using apt-get to remove and reinstall gdm, no difference. I've tried removing gdm and telling it to use lightdm instead, no difference. I have no idea what's going on. Can anyone help?

Comment: Here are screenshots of the error message. I've never seen anything like this.  (http://www.otolith.com/pix/Screenshot_from_2013-12-02_08_25_50.png)  (http://www.otolith.com/pix/Screenshot_from_2013-12-02_08_26_07.png)

Comment: Having no desktop manager when runnign `startx` is normal, you just need to modify your `~/.xinitrc` file to have it point to your DM. What happens if you run `sudo service gdm restart` from the command line instead of `startx`?

Comment: Might be worth trying the following: 1. _purge_ gdm instead of just uninstalling and then reinstall it: `sudo apt-get purge gdm; sudo apt-get install gdm`. 2. Try the same but install another login manager (say lightdm) and then start the relevant service `sudo service lightdm start`, 3. delete the gdm user's home directory, look at `gdm`'s entry in `/etc/passwd`, it should be `/var/lib/gdm`.

Comment: You should definitely report this as a bug, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs -- but first make sure it hasn't been fixed already; I believe the install images can lag behind significantly.  So if you haven't run `apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade` do that first and try a reboot.

Comment: @Turdon Thanks for the advice.  None of the attempts at fixing gdm have worked.  "service restart" produces the same simple-slave error as before, and purge & reinstall produce no error, but neither gets me a desktop manager.  However, "sudo service lightdm start" does get me a desktop manager, so that's good - and it has wiggly windows so I know Compiz is working.  I've spent the last hour or two organizing the week's worth of email and other tasks which were waiting on the desktop manager.

Comment: @Goldilocks I will report the bug and try your advice next.